# Ios Swift decode json data sent from GCM notification

Tags: ios, json, swift2, google-cloud-messaging, anyobject

I am receiving the GCM Json encoded data as AnyObject as below

```
[MsgKey: {"NamKey":"Bdy","MobKey":"9964120147","UidKey":"Uid31"}, collapse_key: do_not_collapse, from: 925652137353]
```

I want to decode the above and pass it to local notication screen

I tried below :

```
func application(appPsgVar: UIApplication,
                 didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject])
{
    print("Notification: ",userInfo["MsgKey"]!)

    let MsgVar = userInfo["MsgKey"]

    var GotVar = MsgVar?.objectAtIndex(2)
|Or|
    var GotVar = MsgVar?.objectForKey("UidKey")
|Or|
    var GotVar = MsgVar?.valueForKey("UidKey")
```

and

```
    if let MsgVar = userInfo["MsgKey"] as? [String:AnyObject]
    {
        GetNfnFnc(MsgVar["NamKey"] as! String)
    }
```

and

```
    if let MsgVar = userInfo["MsgKey"] as? NSData
    {
        var JsnAryVar: AnyObject!
        do
        {
            JsnAryVar = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(MsgVar, options: [])
            print(JsnAryVar)
        }
        catch
        {
            print("ErrVar")
        }

        GetNfnFnc(JsnAryVar["NamKey"] as! String)
    }
}
```

userInfo["MsgKey"] gives me below data and not able understand how to decode further

```
{"NamKey":"Bdy","MobKey":"9964120147","UidKey":"Uid31"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actu the problem was Json encoded data from server was coming as String

Method 1: Suggested by Eric D giving the solution link
[Retrieving values from 2D array in JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34829898/retrieving-values-from-2d-array-in-json-string/34830341#34830341)

```
do
{
    if let MsgCodVar = MsgSrgVar.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding),
     let MsgJsnVar = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(MsgCodVar, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
    {
        print(MsgJsnVar)
    }
}
```

Method 2 : My own hard workaround :-(

Create own function to convert String data to array[String:AnyObject]

```
func CnvJsnSrgTooAryFnc(JsnSrgPsgVar: String) -> [String:AnyObject]
{
    var JsnSrgVar = JsnSrgPsgVar
    JsnSrgVar = JsnSrgVar.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\"", withString: "")
    JsnSrgVar = JsnSrgVar.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("{", withString: "")
    JsnSrgVar = JsnSrgVar.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("}", withString: "")
    let SrgAryVar = JsnSrgVar.componentsSeparatedByString(",")

    var JsnAryVar = [String:AnyObject]()
    for SrgIdxVar in SrgAryVar
    {
        let SrgIdxAryVar = SrgIdxVar.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
        JsnAryVar[SrgIdxAryVar[0]] = SrgIdxAryVar[1]
    }
    return JsnAryVar
}

let MsgAryVar = CnvJsnSrgTooAryFnc(MsgSrgVar)

MsgAryVar["UidKey"]
```

Got output :

```
print(MsgSrgVar) :
{"NamKey":"Bdy","MobKey":"9964120147","UidKey":"Uid99"}

print(MsgAryVar)
["NamKey": Bdy, "MobKey": 9964120147, "UidKey": Uid99]
```

Comment: This is not a good solution for your issue. You should use NSJSONSerialization for the JSON String. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34830341/2227743

Comment: Thanks, I was trying for such simple solution. Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In your third approach, set the `JsnAryVar` type to a Dictionary (`[String: AnyObject]`) and cast the result of `JSONObjectWithData` to a Dictionary.

Follows:

```
var JsnAryVar: [String: AnyObject]!
JsnAryVar = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(MsgVar, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject]
```

Now, you can access the elements inside `MsgKey` as a Dictionary, like `JsnAryVar["NamKey"]`.

Comment: The prob in third case is, the output of <if let MsgVar = userInfo["MsgKey"] as? NSData> is false and never going inside